# using a function with click() javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a function with `click()`. I get no errors in the console how can I make it so that when the click happens it will perform the action in the function? Here is the code I am working with.

```
inputIds = [].filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input'), function(el) {
                return el.id.indexOf('ansx') === 0;
            }).map(function(el) {
                return el.id;
            });
            // random number between low and high range
            inputId = inputIds[Math.floor(Math.random() * inputIds.length)];

    document.getElementById(inputId).click(function() {
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({ message: "text here" }, function(response) {
            return response;
        });
    });
```

Comment: So, is this not working?  Pretty sure the `return response;` isn't actually doing anything.

Comment: @Rocket they work separately but if i try with the code above it does not

Comment: You are selecting an ID at random.  Silly question, but are you trying to click on the right element?

Comment: @Rocket it is selecting at random

Comment: I know it's random, so how you do know you are clicking on the right element?

Comment: @Rocket there is no right or wrong option. Any of the selections will do. I just want to be able to run the function when a selection is clicked

Comment: I think you are missing my point, so never mind.  I was trying to say that since it's random maybe the element you are trying to click on doesn't have the event bound to it.

Answer (score 3):

`click` isn't an event-binding function against a `DOMElement` which `getElementById` returns. As commenters have noted, `click` invokes the event. You need to use jquery or use plain old event handlers.

Comment: It is a function but it doesn't attach event handlers, it simply clicks the element.

Comment: Actually there is [`element.click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click), but it's for triggering the event, not setting it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using any JavaScript framework you should use `addEventListener` instead of `click` function.

```
document.getElementById(inputId).addEventListener("click", function() {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({ message: "text here" }, function(response) {
        return response;
    });
});
```

Comment: @Diogo for example this `document.getElementById(inputId).addEventListener("click", function() { console.log("test") });` it doesn't write to the console

Comment: @Mr.1.0: What is `inputId`?  Does `console.log(document.getElementById(inputId))` print anything?

Comment: @Mr.1.0 the variable `elementId` must refer to the HTML element that when clicked will   execute the function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic implementation of addEvent that works across browsers.

```
function addEvent(el, type, eventHandle){
   if ( el.addEventListener ) {
      el.addEventListener( type, eventHandle, false );
   } else if ( el.attachEvent ) {
      el.attachEvent( "on" + type, eventHandle );
   } else {
      el[type] = eventHandle;
   }
}
```

Your code would look like

```
addEvent(document.getElementById(inputId), "click", function() {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({ message: "text here" }, function(response) {
        return response;
    }); 
  });
```

I would recommend anyone to use a base framework like jQuery as it would mask a lot of such quirks.